# Order jquery functions to happen after another function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that when run, animates a div on my page and removes a class, what I want to do however is remove the class at the end of the height animation, is this possible with jQuery?

```
        var el = $(this).find('ul li'); 
        var img = $(this).find('ul li img');        
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        //return false;
        el.animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
        el.css({
            'background-position':'top left',
            'background-size' : 'auto auto'
        });             


        $(this).find('ul li img').animate({height:'270px'}, 500);
        $(this).animate({height:'135px'}, 500);  

        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return value.substring(28);
        });
```

Comment: Use animate callback function, set your logic there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `complete` function that runs once the animation has completed. According to the [jQuery docs for the `animate` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete), you can use it like so:

```
el.animate({height:'135px'}, 500, function() {
    //code to run when complete goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete call like this inside the .animate function:

```
complete:  function() { your func u wanna call when ani is complete..; }
```